# How to read nth element of each array from a tuple of array at a time

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I want to check whether my array has any duplicate element using `numpy.unique(a,return_count=True)` function where `a = numpy.array([5,2,6,2,7,5,6,8,2,9])`. This function returned tuple of array like:
`(array([2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64))`. Now I want to get the result like:
2 occurs 3 times
5 occurs 2 times
6 occurs 2 times

Any suggestion?

Comment: I want the output in the string format like:                                      2 occurs 3 times                                                                                      5 occurs 2 times

Answer (score 1):

```
In [237]: arr = np.array([5,2,6,2,7,5,6,8,2,9])                                                                                           
In [241]: np.unique(arr,return_counts=True)                                     
Out[241]: (array([2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]))

In [242]: u,cnt = np.unique(arr,return_counts=True)
```

Paired in a dictionary:

```
In [243]: {k:v for k,v in zip(u,cnt)}                                           
Out[243]: {2: 3, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1}
```

or a list of tuples:

```
In [244]: list(zip(u,cnt))                                                      
Out[244]: [(2, 3), (5, 2), (6, 2), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1)]
```

This is a kind of transpose, akin to the array:

```
In [246]: np.array((u,cnt)).T                                                   
Out[246]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [5, 2],
       [6, 2],
       [7, 1],
       [8, 1],
       [9, 1]])
```